Does it matter to deselect faces before going back to Object Mode?
When editing geometry, faces are automatically selected and can still be selected when going back to Object Mode. Does this have an effect on memory or performance? After completing geometry edits, if vertices, edges, and faces are still selected, it 'feels' weird, but I don't know if it really matters.

Yes, it makes a difference for the memory. Although this should be negligible if your PC is not an absolute potato.
For example, when I create an object with around 2 million vertices, the object uses ca. 400 MB in Object Mode and 2.4 GB in Edit Mode. The difference between no vertex selected and all 2 million is about 20 MB.
So I would suspect when your PC can handle the 2.4 GB, the 20 MB (or less if not all are selected) difference should not matter.
What adds up to the memory is when you select and deselect a few times, because the amount of Undo steps will increase.

Interesting find, nice detective work. One other potential implication is for scripting. While uncommon, scripts may use Edit Mode selection to operate even under Object Mode.

@Gordon Brinkmann: Du hast zuviel Zeit! :D ...but interesting! upvote!

@Chris Ach was :D I made a cube, subdivided it a lot and duplicated it many times in Edit Mode, then I looked at the memory usage. Did not take much time, less than a minute ;)

Idk about memory stuff but when you use and apply a boolean, if you didn't have any faces selected in the object that gets the modifier, and some or all the faces on the cutting object were selected, the new faces created by the cut will be selected as well when you go into edit mode again. Which makes it easier to add them to a vertex group or modify them in some other way.



Pretty cool, I think all attributes work this way: material indices, sharp edges etc.
